mariadb not save result to the table by kotlin
import java.io.File
import java.sql.Connection
import java.sql.DriverManager
import java.sql.PreparedStatement
import java.sql.Statement
import com.google.gson.Gson
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken

data class InputData(val data: List<String>)
data class RegexPatterns(val regex_patterns: Map<String, String>)

fun main() {
    // Load input data from input.json
    val inputFile = File("src/main/resources/input.json")
    val inputData: InputData = Gson().fromJson(inputFile.reader(), InputData::class.java)

    // Load regex patterns from regex.json
    val regexFile = File("src/main/resources/regex.json")
    val regexType = object : TypeToken<RegexPatterns>() {}.type
    val regexPatterns: RegexPatterns = Gson().fromJson(regexFile.reader(), regexType)

    // MariaDB connection details
    val jdbcUrl = "jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/sensitive_data"
    val username = "root"
    val password = "your_password"

    // Connect to MariaDB
    val connection: Connection = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl, username, password)

    // Prepare SQL statement for inserting regex patterns into information_type table
    val insertPatternSQL = "INSERT INTO information_type (name, pattern) VALUES (?, ?)"
    val patternPreparedStatement: PreparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(insertPatternSQL, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS)

    // Insert regex patterns into the information_type table and create corresponding tables for matched values
    val categoryIds = mutableMapOf<String, Int>()
    regexPatterns.regex_patterns.forEach { (category, pattern) ->
        // Insert category and pattern into information_type table
        patternPreparedStatement.setString(1, category)
        patternPreparedStatement.setString(2, pattern)
        patternPreparedStatement.executeUpdate()

        // Get the generated ID for the inserted category
        val generatedKeys = patternPreparedStatement.generatedKeys
        if (generatedKeys.next()) {
            val categoryId = generatedKeys.getInt(1)
            categoryIds[category] = categoryId
            println("Inserted pattern for category: $category with ID: $categoryId")

            // Sanitize the table name
            val tableName = category.replace(" ", "_").replace("'", "").replace("-", "_").replace(",", "").replace("&", "and")
            // Create a new table for the matched values of this category
            val createTableSQL = """
                CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `$tableName` (
                    ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
                    data TEXT
                ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci
            """.trimIndent()
            val statement: Statement = connection.createStatement()
            statement.executeUpdate(createTableSQL)
            println("Created table: $tableName")
        }
    }

    // Prepare SQL statements for inserting matched and non-matched data
    val insertNonMatchedSQL = "INSERT INTO `non-matched` (data) VALUES (?)"
    val nonMatchedPreparedStatement: PreparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(insertNonMatchedSQL)

    val insertMatchedSQLs = categoryIds.mapValues { (category, _) ->
        val tableName = category.replace(" ", "_").replace("'", "").replace("-", "_").replace(",", "").replace("&", "and")
        connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO `$tableName` (data) VALUES (?)")
    }

    // Iterate over each data entry and match with the appropriate pattern
    inputData.data.forEach { entry ->
        var matched = false
        regexPatterns.regex_patterns.forEach { (category, pattern) ->
            val regex = Regex(pattern)
            if (regex.matches(entry)) {
                println("\"$category\": \"$entry\"")
                // Insert the matching result into the corresponding table
                insertMatchedSQLs[category]?.setString(1, entry)
                insertMatchedSQLs[category]?.executeUpdate()
                matched = true
                return@forEach
            }
        }
        if (!matched) {
            println("Non-matched data: \"$entry\"")
            nonMatchedPreparedStatement.setString(1, entry)
            nonMatchedPreparedStatement.executeUpdate()
        }
    }

    // Close the connection
    connection.close()
    println("Data processing complete. Connection closed.")
}


This is my code to match the input with regex pattern. If an input is matched with a pattern, then store that input into the corresponding table with that pattern. If an input is NOT matched with any pattern, then store that input in the non_matched table.
After running this code, it can match correctly but the inputs are NOT stored in the tables. How can I fixed this?
I think there are mistake in these line:
"val insertNonMatchedSQL = "INSERT INTO `non-matched` (data) VALUES (?)"
"connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO `$tableName` (data) VALUES (?)")"

is the VALUES (?) correct?
I would like to store the input data with the corresponding table in the DB

Have you checked the return value from the executeUpdate() calls? Have you tried close()ing your statements before closing the connection?  — But quite a bit of that code looks irrelevant; can you try to simplify it it down to a minimal reproducible example?

the results for executeUpdate() are all 1

Please provide the generated SQL and SHOW CREATE TABLE.
